# Display a vector tile layer in Openlayers with layer from arcgis REST map server

Tags: rest, openlayers, arcgis, arcgis-server, osm.pbf

I work with a quite big [feature layer](https://gisp.dfo-mpo.gc.ca/arcgis/rest/services/FGP/Eastern_Canada_Marine_Spatial_Planning_Areas/MapServer/0) that is hosted in a arcgis map server. Because of its size, loading it in Openlayers as a VectorLayer is too slow (there is about 50mb of data to load, which can take up to 10 seconds to do so). I wish to switch to vector tile layer source, which would enable to load only the data needed, depending on the zoom level.
I tried using the same approach the [arcgis doc](https://developers.arcgis.com/openlayers/key-concepts/#publish-and-display-a-vector-tile-layer) says to do for vector tile server, but it doesnt work, and gives me the following error:

> index.js:207 Uncaught Error: Unimplemented type: 4
> at Pbf.skip (index.js:207:1)

It would actually make sense if it doesnt work, but at the same time, the same layer is used in a [argis online app](https://gisp.dfo-mpo.gc.ca/apps/Atlas-Atlantique/?locale=fr)  . And the layer is loaded a lot faster, using tiles. Here is a snippet of the network tab zooming in:
[image]
So, do you know a way to optimize this type of service in Openlayers, somewhat like it is done in arcgis online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ArcGIS PBF data is not compatible with MVT, you need a parser https://github.com/rowanwins/arcgis-pbf-parser for the client to convert to it a GeoJSON format which OpenLayers can understand.

Working example https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-esri-forked-h9jz7q?file=/main.js

Example without tiling https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-esri-forked-3m33jm?file=/main.js

Comment: Hi! Thanks for you quick reply. It works indeed! But you probably noticed in your example that it is still quite long to load the data when you zoom in. Would you have any tips on how I can improve speed rendering? Thanks again

Comment: PBF is smaller than a JSON download but it still includes the full geometry of features which intersect an extent (unlike MVT tiles where geometries are clipped to the buffered tile extent) so when you have a small number of large features there is nothing to be gained by tiling.  But using PBF for the data in a regular vector layer will reduce your 50MB download to less than 7MB
https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-esri-forked-3m33jm?file=/main.js

Comment: It really do helps to render the layer as a vectorLayer indeed. 
The only problem is that sometimes, the layer wont render at all. The ressource is stuck to pending. After about 20 seconds, I get the following error:
`Uncaught Error: Could not parse arcgis-pbf buffer
    at decode (arcgis-pbf.cjs:556:11)
    at EsriPBF.readFeatures (main.js:23:22)
    at xhr.onload (featureloader.js:33:24)`
Im not sure it is part of the original question, so I will still mark this question as accepted, but if you have any idea of why it creates this error once in a while, that would further help me. Thx!